# Seeking hard water data source

Tags: data-request, usa

I'm in need of finding a data source that I can use to create a heat map showing varying water hardness in the U.S.

I've tried the usual, i.e. usgs, epa, and I'm not able to find what I need.

I'd like to make something similar to this (I can't find the original creator so I have to make my own

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I've been looking for a similar dataset. So far I found this but have no way of actually downloading it since it's too big (I think).

This is real data and pre-collated to include several definitions of hardness. I'm still exploring the page but I think it could be possible to get the geographical data too:
https://www.waterqualitydata.us/#countrycode=US&sampleMedia=Water&characteristicName=Hardness&characteristicName=Hardness%2C%20Ca%2C%20Mg&characteristicName=Hardness%2C%20carbonate&characteristicName=Total%20hardness&characteristicName=Hardness%2C%20non-carbonate&mimeType=csv&dataProfile=narrowResult&providers=NWIS&providers=STEWARDS&providers=STORET

Comment: I've used that source before, but now I am having issues getting it to return any data to me, either by browser or curl.

Answer (score 0):

Water hardness is not measured by the EPA or similar sites, like [MyTapWater.org](https://mytapwater.org), EWG etc. I'd look into private datasets from [MyTapScore](https://mytapscore.com/pages/the-lead-map), who has released similar data sets.

Comment: Thanks.  Checked into it.  MyTapScore gave me access to their db, but it's a web based street by street inquiry, so that's not going to work.  They also source some their data from government sources such as:

SDWIS, 
ECHO, 
UCMR 4, 
US Geological Survey’s National Water Information System (NWIS), 
Environmental Protection Agency’s Storage and Retrieval data warehouse (STORET), 
US Department of Agriculture’s Sustaining Earth’s Watersheds - Agricultural Research Database System (STEWARDS), 
National Water Quality Monitoring Portal (WQP).

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this open dataset about water quality. It shows much more than just hardness but I'm not sure if it can help you:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/adityakadiwal/water-potability

Comment: Thanks.  It seems that this dataset is fake.  The numbers and discussion verify that it isn't real world data.